# OOP Loop Help Needed

Tags: php, loops

I have scoured the net and watched endless You Tube vids but cant find an answer to this. Most of what I am finding is for more complex issues and I am just a newbie starting out.

I am trying to learn OOP. I took an old PHP example I had lying around and decided to try converting it to oop. All it is is a loop with a counter. Problem is I cant get it to work out at all.

My original view page was this...

```
<html>
<head><title>1 Loop</title></head>
<body>
<h2>1 Loop for age</h2>
<?php
$age=18;
while ($age <= 20)
{ 
echo ("You are " . $age . " years old. <br /> You are not old enough to enter. <br /><br />");
$age++;
}
echo ("You are " . $age . " You may enter!");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am trying to create a class_lib page and a php page. Here is my class page:

```
<?php 
class person {

public $age; 

    function __construct($persons_age) { 
        $this->age = $persons_age;    
                   }

function get_age() {

while ($age <= 20)
{ 
echo ("You are " . $age . " years old. <br /> You are not old enough to enter. <br /><br />");
$age++;
}
echo ("You are " . $age . " You may enter!");

return $this->age;  
echo $this->age;   
                       }

         }
?>
```

And lastly, my php view:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>1 Loop</title>
<?php include("class_lib.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>
<h2>1 Loop for age</h2>

<?php

$obj = new person(17);
echo $obj->get_age();

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone give me a few pointers as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Since you're getting started, I think it's worth mentioning that a method named `getSomething()` would normally be expected not to modify the variable, just to return the relevant data. I know this is just a test program, so I don't want you to think I'm being critical; just trying to help; it's just something that's good to know. Seeing the `++` in a `get` method... there's nothing technically incorrect about it; it just looks weird.

Comment: Why the hell you want to turn a perfectly legitimate template in "OOP code"? What the point here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `get_age()` function you use `$age` instead of using `$this->age`. The latter uses the class variable, instead of a local variable (that does not exist).

Remove the `echo $this->age;` line which resides after the `return`-statement of the function. It is never reached and does not seem to have any value, as you already printed the age.

Comment: +1: the first point is where the problem is. (The second point is just a case of tidying up)

Comment: Worked amazingly!! Cant believe thats all I was doing but your explanation helped me understand the whole "This->" thing better too!

Answer (score 1):

Your get_age() function is wrong, you're trying to access the $age variable like a local variable though it should be accessed like a class variable.
Try this:

```
function get_age() {

while ($this->age <= 20)
{ 
echo ("You are " . $this->age . " years old. <br /> You are not old enough to enter. <br /><br />");
$this->age++;
}
echo ("You are " . $this->age . " You may enter!");

return $this->age;   
                       }
```

Remove the echo function, the last line of it, because this will never get called since you any code after the return call is dismissed.
Also, you're already echoing the content you're returning in your php view.